# jquery.appear - How to add on a canvas-element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas, appearance

How to add the **[jquery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear)**-Plugin to this canvas-element (id="pic")? The script itself is already included into the html-page, but how to make the canvas-image only visible, if the element is on the screen?

```
<canvas id="pic"></canvas> 

<script type="text/javascript">    

var picData6 = whatever1
var options =  whatever2  

var ct6 = document.getElementById("pic").getContext("2d");
ct6.canvas.width = document.getElementById("pic").offsetWidth-4;
ct6.canvas.height = document.getElementById("pic").offsetHeight;
var Chart6  = new Chart(ct6).Line(picData6,options);

</script>
```

It seems the **.appear()** has to be add somewhere. But where?

Thank you very much!

Comment: According to the documentation $('someselector').appear(); someselector can be "#pic"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery.appear simply gives you custom `appear` and `disappear` events for elements which you have registered.

To add it to your canvas, you would do something like:

```
// register the element with the plugin
$('#pic').appear();

// do this when it appears
$('#pic').on('appear', function(ev, elements) {

    // elements is an array of elements which are now visible on the page

});
```

Comment: Okay, it works that way: `$("#pic").appear();
$("#pic").on('appear', function (){var Chart6  = new Chart(ct6).Line(picData6,options);});`